# java Rectangle getHeight() odd behaviour

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to build a rectangle within a rectangle.  Rectangle "walls" should be in a particular position with a height that is bg.getHeight() - ground.getHeight().  For some reason, the rectangle "walls" still extends to the bottom of the applet.  All other values such as the width and positions are working fine.  With a 300 height applet, if i subtract a static 120, it works, but the value of ground.getHeight is actually 60, and if i subtract 60, it still extends all the way down to the border. i am confused with the inconsistency.

---

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class House_JM extends JApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics page) {
        Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, (int) (getSize().height * .8), getSize().width,
                (int) (getSize().height * .2));
        Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(0, 0, getSize().width, (int) (getSize().height * .8));
        page.setColor(Color.green);
        page.fillRect((int) ground.getX(), (int) ground.getY(), (int) ground.getWidth(), (int) ground.getHeight());
        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fillRect((int) bg.getX(), (int) bg.getY(), (int) bg.getWidth(), (int) bg.getHeight());
        Rectangle walls = new Rectangle((int) (bg.getWidth() / 2 - bg.getWidth() * .1), (int) (bg.getHeight() * .5),
                (int) (bg.getWidth() * .4), (int) ((bg.getHeight() - ground.getHeight())));
        page.setColor(Color.red);
        page.fillRect((int) walls.getX(), (int) walls.getY(), (int) walls.getWidth(), (int) walls.getHeight());
        System.out.println(bg.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve], a ***small*** program with code that we can copy, paste, compile and run, and that demonstrates your problem. Not asking for the entire program, just enough that we can fully test.

Comment: Also, are you drawing directly within the applet? Don't do that but instead draw within a JPanel that is displayed by the applet. Also, why are you even using applets as this technology has been deprecated by Oracle?

Comment: Edited post with complete code. I am using an applet because it is a school assignment.

Comment: The problem is nothing more than that your math is off. Draw it on paper using a pencil and you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the answer was already given in the comments: "Your math is off". The computations that you did have simply been wrong and did not make sense.

<sub>The main reason of why I'm answering this (otherwise poor) question is that I wondered: How is it possible that someone writes this code, and thinks that it might even be *remotely* acceptable in terms of style? Yes, "style" may be subjective, to some extent. But when comparing the code in the question, and the code below, one could have a hard time arguing about this...</sub>

Here is a an example that shows the result that you are likely trying to achieve:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class House_JM extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D page = (Graphics2D)g;

        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        Rectangle2D ground = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            0, h * 0.8, w, h * 0.2);

        Rectangle2D bg = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            0, 0, w, h * 0.8);

        Rectangle2D walls = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            bg.getWidth() * 0.5 - bg.getWidth() * 0.1, 
            bg.getHeight() * 0.5,
            bg.getWidth() * 0.4, 
            h * 0.4);

        page.setColor(Color.green);
        page.fill(ground);
        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fill(bg);
        page.setColor(Color.red);
        page.fill(walls);

        System.out.println(bg.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Note that the height of the `walls` rectangle has to be the height of the applet times 0.4, because it *starts*  at `bg.getHeight() * 0.5`, which is the height of the applet times 0.4, and the floor has a height of 0.2 times the height of the applet.

Comment: Ok, thanks. that got me started. My goal was to be able to call on only the attributes of the surrounding shape instead of the applet. i may want to break this up differently after it is built and i wanted each part contained.
I took the "h * 0.4", which of course works,  and did "(int)(bg.getHeight() * .5)" which got me the the same correct result and in the fashion i wanted.
As for style, being 3 chapters into my first semester of programming, I guess I am just not that polished. :)

Comment: I like the idea putting the color fill section seperately.  didnt know about page.fill()